# "Abstract type X must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.user with value

Tags: node.js, graphql-js, apollo-server

this my code

**schema**

```
gql`
  type Query {
    user: X!
  }
  type User {
    name: String!
  }
  type Time {
    age: Int!
  }
  union X = User | Time
`;
```

**resolvers**

```
{
  X: {
    __resolveType: obj => {
      if (obj.name) return { name: "Amasia" };
      if (obj.age) return { age: 70 };
      return null;
    }
  },
  Query: {
    user: () => {
      return {
        name: "Amasia"
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**request**

```
query {
user{
  ... on User {
    name
  }
  ... on Time {
    age
  }
}
}
```

When I make a request do I get Error

> "Abstract type X must resolve to an Object type at runtime for field Query.user with value { name: \"Amasia\" }, received \"{ name: \"Amasia\" }\". Either the X type should provide a \"resolveType\" function or each possible type should provide an \"isTypeOf\" function."

What is the reason.?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `resolveType` function should return a string with the name of the concrete type the abstract type should resolve to. You are returning an object, not string. In this case, you should return `"User"` or `"Time"`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! it helped me! I also wanted to add on. If you have the resolveType setup correctly and still getting the error, check your Query's returning data. I was looking for obj.title but turns out, the obj was obj.Items with array, so couldn't find title property.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the `__typename` to the object to resolve it:

```
 {
  Query: {
    user: () => {
      return {
        __typename: 'User',
        name: "Amasia"
      };
    }
  }
}
```